# Class 'MongoClient' not found

Tags: php, mongodb

I'm trying to make this code run:

```
<?php

$m = new MongoClient("mongodb://54.72.237.242"); 
$db = $m->tilbud; 

?>
```

Everytime I got the same error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'MongoClient' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\conexion.php
```

I've been reading about this problem the whole day but anything solves my issue (I guess it's something I'm doing wrong).

I downloaded the php_mongo.dll, I copied it in xampp/php/ext and I added `extension=php_mongo.dll` in the php.ini archive.

I've added 4 more dll's because I'm not sure which one I have to use:

- `extension=php_mongo-1.5.4-5.5-vc11-nts`
- `extension=php_mongo-1.5.4-5.5-vc11`
- `extension=php_mongo-1.5.4-5.5-vc11-nts-x86_64`
- `extension=php_mongo-1.5.4-5.5-vc11-x86_64`

So now im getting 5 warnings instead of one. At the end I guess one of them will work and I'll delete the other 4.

Things I tried and I'm sure they are ok:

- The extension_dir is pointing to the correct folder.
- The php.ini that I modified is the one that xammp loads.
- Phpinfo dosen't show anything about mongo.

What more can I try ?

**Edit**

I tried

> echo extension_loaded("mongo") ? "loaded\n" : "not loaded\n";

and it always says 'not loaded'.

**Edit**

Finally!
The problem was the dll's name. It has to be 'php_mongo.dll' and I was trying to load the full name dll as I said at the begining of this post. So I changed the correct dll for me (`extension=php_mongo-1.5.4-5.5-vc11`) for `extension=php_mongo.dll` and voilà!

Comment: Downloading the dll is not enough. Follow the installation instructions here: http://php.net/manual/en/mongo.installation.php

Comment: Thank you but i've followed those instructions already.

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/37261957/2123530

Answer (score 38):

You have not installed MongoDB PHP driver please see this link http://www.php.net/manual/en/mongo.installation.php

Update sources

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 7F0CEB10
echo 'deb http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/ubuntu-upstart dist 10gen' | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb.list
sudo apt-get update
```

Install MongoDB PHP Driver

```
sudo apt-get install php5-dev php5-cli php-pear -y
sudo pecl install mongo
```

Open your php.ini file and add to it:

```
extension=mongo.so
```

Restart apache

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

***Other helping info:***

this should help to find your php.ini file:

```
php -i | grep 'Configuration File'
```

On Ubuntu it shows this:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /etc/php5/cli
Loaded Configuration File => /etc/php5/cli/php.ini
```

take a note, that you run this command from cli (command line) so for your true php.ini go to folder apache2 instead of cli :)

Comment: Use `printf "\n" | pecl install mongo` if You need to integrate it into an install script.

Comment: In the original question there is a reference to `C:\xampp\htdocs` which indicates that they are using Windows, and therefore none of these commands will help them at all.

Comment: good point nevada_scount, thanks. I hope my answer will still be usefull to all who are using linux.

Comment: **Solved**! I have problem with extension name, extension= **mongodb.so** -> **mongo.so**

Answer (score 29):

For those arriving on this page with PHP 7 installed:

The `MongoCLient` class was provided by `pecl install mongo`.
But `pecl/mongo` is not available for php7 and deprecated in favor of `pecl/mongodb`. But with `pecl/mongodb` you'll need to use [MongoDB\Driver\Manager](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongodb-driver-manager.php) instead of [MongoClient](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongoclient.php) (warning on page says so too).

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34508341/4126114) for further reading.

This said, you will need an abstraction layer on top of the PHP `MongoDB\Driver\Manager`. This is provided by [mongodb/mongo-php-library](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-library).

You will need to refactor stuff like:

- `\MongoClient` to `\MongoDB\Client`
- `\MongoCollection` to `\MongoDB\Collection`
- `\MongoClient->selectDB` to `\MongoDB\Client->selectDatabase`
- `\MongoClient->listDBs` to `\MongoDB\Client->listDatabases`

  - also output is not an array but an iterator, so you'll need to use `iterator_to_array`, along with edits to how you use the resulting object
- `\MongoCollection->getName` to `\MongoDB\Collection->getCollectionName`
- `\MongoCollection->update` to `\MongoDB\Collection->updateOne` or `updateMany`
- `\MongoCollection->remove` to `\MongoDB\Collection->deleteOne`
- `\MongoCollection->batchInsert` to `\MongoDB\Collection->insertMany`

Comment:  why are they making us refactor everything? So sad

Comment: You can also use this plugin on top of php mongodb client to use the old methods and classes on the new driver : https://github.com/alcaeus/mongo-php-adapter

Answer (score 4):

The answer is indeed to follow the instructions.
I was missing the very important **require** line that must come before creating the new mongodb object:

```
<?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$client = new MongoDB\Client("mongodb://localhost:27017");
```

And of course you need to run this command in the root of your project as per the instructions:

```
composer require mongodb/mongodb
```

Answer (score 3):

Getting the same error and now it's solved.
I am using Linux Mint. To solve this issue I added `extension=mongo.so`  in two directories:

- /etc/php5/cli/php.ini
- /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini

Answer (score 3):

install the driver, I have for example php5.6:

```
sudo apt-get install php5.6-mongo
```

Comment: +1 to this response, but it helps me, becose i've added before this repository https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php

Answer (score 2):

From [this](http://php.net/manual/en/mongo.installation.php#mongo.installation.windows) page:

**Note: Additional DLL dependencies for Windows Users:**

In order for this extension to work, there are DLL files that must be available to the Windows system PATH

Answer (score 0):

your php version and dll file version should be same check it if versions are not same then update your xampp php according to the available dll version.