# Cant install mongo into PHP (XAMPP, Windows)

Tags: php, mongodb, xampp

I'm sitting on it 3rd day and i have no idea what to do next.

I'm using XAMPP on Windows.

I've downloaded mongo.dll from here:https://pecl.php.net/package/mongo/1.5.5/windows - for php5.6, TS, x32.

i've modified php.ini file.

When i run "php -m" i can see "mongo" on modules list. But when i open my page, i see "Class 'MongoClient' not found" error message.

i've tried also to type "php install mongo" but after some time i see message "Package "mongo" Version "1.6.10" does not have REST xml available
install failed"

I have installed mongo on my computer, but i don't think it's realy needed since i'm going to connect to another computer in LAN.

[UPDATE]

When i run phpinfo by www, there is no mongo on list.

when i run php -i, mongo is there.

I could understand, if there was another php.ini for CLI and Apache, but there is no other php.ini on my computer.

Comment: I'm not sure how Xampp does things these days, but on my Linux servers, I have a separate ini file for command line and web. Can you create a script with the following and see if it mentions mongo as well? `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`

Comment: Do you follow the instructions http://php.net/manual/en/mongo.installation.php?

Comment: May be it helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24533938/class-mongoclient-not-found

Comment: I've seen both sites.

Comment: Voting to close this as off-topic. This is by far better suited for serverfault.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg  - on server fault this question was closed, because it belongs to stackoverflow.