# Using "Legacy" MongoDB Driver with PHP7

Tags: mongodb, php-7, php-mongodb

Is there a way to use the [Legacy Mongo PHP Driver](https://pecl.php.net/package/mongo) from PECL with PHP7? Maybe unofficial fork with PHP7 support or compile/modification instruction...

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34486808/installing-the-php-7-mongodb-client-driver/34584135 I realized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an alternative if you really need to use any bundle or library with strong dependencies on php mongo legacy driver, it's called "alcaeus:mongo-php-adapter".  It provides an ext-mongo library on top of mongo-php-library (sic).

https://github.com/alcaeus/mongo-php-adapter

If you face any problem with composer related with the absence of legacy driver (Famous message "The requested PHP extension ext-mongo * is missing") you can fix it adding that to composer.json

"provide": {
    "ext-mongo": "1.6.12"
},

In this case may be you want to take a look to this thread (same situation but with heroku):  https://github.com/alcaeus/mongo-php-adapter/issues/67

Answer (score 0):

No, the legacy driver does not support PHP7. Here's [the commit](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-driver-legacy/commit/e3d742388794e110a9a52feff1348c1cae648bcc) and the [JIRA Ticket](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/PHP-1474) where this was officially finalized.

The new PHP MongoDB driver can be found [in PECL here](https://pecl.php.net/package/mongodb) (or [GitHub](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-driver)).

To install, just:

```
pecl channel-update pecl.php.net

pecl install mongodb

echo "extension=mongodb.so" >> `php --ini | grep "Loaded Configuration" | sed -e "s|.*:\s*||"`
```

The documentation for the new driver can be found [here](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-php-driver/). I'd like to include a note from the documentation:

> Ultimately, this extension is not intended to be used alone. Users should considering using this driver alongside one or more userland PHP libraries, such as [mongo-php-library](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-library).

The new `mongodb` driver / PHP extension is a lot more low-level than the legacy `mongo` driver, and you are encouraged to use a higher-level library on top of the driver rather than using it directly in your code.

The [Mongo PHP Library](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-library/) ([releases](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-library/releases)) is the official high-level library for PHP, and it's what is recommended to use in your projects. It's still in Beta, but this still seems to be the safest and most-future-proof path forward with PHP7.

**Edit**: The Legacy Mongo Driver is no longer active at all.

Comment: First of all, thx for edit. From right question to wrong.
I know about last commit. I know about new driver. I'm finding the way to use legacy driver with PHP7. That's what I'm asking about.

Comment: No problem. Right, the legacy driver simply won't work with PHP7. You'd have to modify it by hand to be compatible with the new API. I think this would be a good time to switch to the new driver.