# PHP 7 and MongoDB Driver

Tags: php, mongodb, php-7

As we know, there is a new PHP 7 MongoDB driver, and lots of classes and functions are replaced by new ones. So can anyone give me a quick example of how to use MongoDB with PHP7 properly?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34486808/installing-the-php-7-mongodb-client-driver

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, but the question you ask is not suitable in stackoverflow, please take look at here. http://stackoverflow.com/help

Comment: Now it's more on-topic! :)

Answer (score -1):

1) I advise you to use the PHP Library :
https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-library

2) Here is some code I use to connect to DB / collection

```
$client = new MongoDB\Client("mongodb://USER:PASSWORD@localhost:27017/BaseName");
$collection = $client->BaseName->CollectionName;
```

3) Example of FindOne query :

```
$document = $collection->findOne(
            ['SomeField' => ''$var'']
            );
```

4) Check out the docs of the library here , they give a few examples.
https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-library