# setup mongoDB-extension for php7

Tags: php, mongodb, ubuntu

I'm trying to install the mongoDB-extension for php7. I started with a brand new installation of Ubuntu-Server 16.04.1. Pre-installed (while OS-installation) packages were LAMP-extension, OpenSSL and MySQL-server. This was installed on a local VirtualBox. It shall to be a development system which is configured equal for every developer.

First I installed MongoDB itself according to these instructions: [install mongoDB on Ubuntu](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mongodb-on-ubuntu-16-04)

After that, according to this second instruction: [installing php7-mongoDB-client-driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34486808/installing-the-php-7-mongodb-client-driver),

I installed

- php-pear
- phpize

It can be recapped in

```
$sudo apt-get install php-pear phpize
```

because these two packages were flagged as missing when using

```
sudo pecl install mongodb
```

the first time.

Then I was suggested to install openssl-extension. About that I found an instruction which told me to execute these 3 commands:

- `$sudo apt-get install libssl-dev`
- `$sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev`
- `$sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev pkg-config libssl-dev libsslcommon2-dev`

(the first package was already installed on my system)

after that

```
$php -m
```

should show "openssl" as a single point on the list.

Then I could finally execute

```
$sudo pecl install mongodb
```

This installation displayed four instructions at the end:

```
<Installing '/usr/lib/php/20151012/mongodb.so'>
<install ok: channel://pecl.php.net/mongodb-1.1.8>
<configuration option "php_ini" is not set to php.ini location>
<You should add "extension=mongodb.so" to php.ini>
```

So I executed:

```
$php -i | grep extension_dir
```

which should show up the same path as displayed in the first line.

```
$pear config-set php_ini /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
$pecl config-set php_ini /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
```

to follow the instructions of the third line.

Added `extension=mongodb.so` to phpini at `/etc/php/7.0/apache2/` 
to conform to line four.

And finally, after restarted apache2,

```
$php -i
```

should display the same version of mongodb similar in the second line.

After all of these steps I found one last package to install which is

```
$sudo apt-get install php-mongodb
```

But also this this didn't help.

To check if the extension is working I used either:

```
$m = new MongoClient();  OR

$m = new Mongo\Driver\Manager();
```

and then echo $m. I read that `Mongo\Driver\Manager` is the new version but even with this code it doesn't work. It always tells me that the class "could not be found". Irrespective of the class I tried.

I hope this (hopefully) complete instruction can help someone with a similar problem about mongodb and php.

Additionally I hope that these information can help you to give me a hint what else I can do to fix that problem. Unfortunately I searched a long time but didn't found something to include this extension into this php-version.
There where only part but I cant build them together.

Comment: Have you check this solid reply? http://stackoverflow.com/a/34508341/3081659

Comment: yes, I found that but those steps (listed in the answers below) are the same I proceeded. I installed pecl, mongodb and I don't use any framework. Maybe I missed something but I would say I already tried all of these steps.
However, thank u for this hit.

Answer (score 4):

When using PHP 7+ install new Mongo PHP Adapter

```
 composer config "platform.ext-mongo" "1.6.16" && composer require alcaeus/mongo-php-adapter
```

Then install mongodb with PECL

```
pecl install mongodb
```

And if you installed correctly the mongodb

```
$ sudo nano /etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini
```

Add the following line in the file:

```
extension = mongodb.so;
```

or with this command

```
echo "extension=mongodb.so" >> `php --ini | grep "Loaded Configuration" | sed -e "s|.*:\s*||"`
```

Comment: SO don't allow edit thare are less than 6 characters : so on the line : extension = mongo.so;, it's extension = mongodb.so; (the alternate way is correct)

Comment: is there a non-pecl way to install MongoDB??  Or I need pear to get pecl? The occasional PHP user finds this very confusing thx.

Comment: If for some reason that extension isn't loaded and you are on ubuntu, this command works `sudo apt-get install php7.4-mongodb`

Answer (score 1):

For docker, I just added below line to the `Dockerfile`:

```
RUN pecl install mongodb && docker-php-ext-enable mongodb
```

or

```
pecl install mongodb-1.5.0

docker-php-ext-enable mongodb
```