# PHP Fatal error: Class 'MongoClient' not found while installing rawdatabse script on remote linux server

Tags: php, mongodb, ubuntu

I am working on a project that consist of raw database to be made available while making project live on remote server. I have my linux server on which i did installation by following [this link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu)

I installed apache2 & php with above link

Then i installed mongodb by following [this link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mongodb-on-ubuntu-14-04)

here when i installed, it gave me following output

```
root@GoTutor:~# sudo apt-get install mongodb-org
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package mongodb-org
```

So i installed mongodb with this command:

```
sudo apt-get install mongodb
```

Now i am running script on it whose starting segment is as follows:

```
$m = new MongoClient();
echo "Connection to database successfully";
```

here it has showed me following error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'MongoClient' not found in /root/createRawCities.php on line 3
```

What to do in this case?
Thanks

Comment: Seems like you haven't installed the mongo php extension, read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24533938/class-mongoclient-not-found) on how to install it

Comment: are you talking about remote server linux where i have deployed my project & not on localhost?

Comment: Wherever if fails i guess :-)

Comment: as per the mongodb documentation u no need to install drivers on server manually as mongodb do so itself.