# MongoClient on 32-bit Linux and PHP < 7 without refactoring

Tags: php, linux, mongodb

I have an error saying MongoClient class is not found.

I've tried both the instructions on the [MongoDB website](https://docs.mongodb.com/v2.4/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-debian/) and [these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24533938/class-mongoclient-not-found).

Upon `php -v` there is

```
PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20131226/mongo.so' 
PHP 5.6.30-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 (cli) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.6-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2016, by Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 2002-2016, by Derick Rethans
```

with `sudo grep -rnw /etc -e "mongo.so"`

I have

```
/etc/php/5.6/fpm/php.ini:2033:extension=mongo.so
/etc/php/5.6/cli/php.ini:2032:extension=mongo.so
/etc/php/5.6/apache2/php.ini:2033:extension=mongo.so
```

Then I tried the [manual installation.](http://php.net/manual/de/mongo.installation.php#mongo.installation.manual)

When I run `phpize`

```
PHP Api Version:         20121113
Zend Module Api No:      20121212
Zend Extension Api No:   220121212
```

At the make test output I get

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: mongo: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20121212
PHP    compiled with module API=20131226
```

How do I compile the correct module?

I've removed php 7 entirely

```
sudo apt-get purge php7.*
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you had installed the wrong extension for your system.

I suggest to start fresh and use pecl to install and compile mongo extension properly.

- [Install pecl](https://askubuntu.com/questions/403327/install-pecl-packages-on-ubuntu/403348) (assuming that you are using Debian-based distribution with correct apt repos, pecl comes bundled with php-pear)

  ```
  sudo apt-get install php5-dev php-pear
  ```
- Install the [legacy mongo driver](https://pecl.php.net/package/mongo) from pecl

  ```
  sudo pecl install mongo
  ```
- Add `extension=mongo.so` on php.ini

  ```
  sudo su
  echo "extension=mongo.so" >> /etc/php5/mods-available/mongo.ini
  ln -rs /etc/php5/mods-available/mongo.ini /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/30-mongo.ini
  ln -rs /etc/php5/mods-available/mongo.ini /etc/php5/fpm/conf.d/30-mongo.ini
  ln -rs /etc/php5/mods-available/mongo.ini /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/30-mongo.ini
  ```

Note that the legacy driver is not compatible with PHP 7+ and the lastest version of MongoDB one can use with this driver is 3.0. See the [compatibility chart from MongoDB Docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/drivers/php/#mongodb-compatibility).

Comment: I had already done the first two. It was part of your third point that worked. Thanks