# Can't connect mongoDB with PHP?

Tags: php, mongodb, xampp

I imported the proper mongodb.dll file in php/ext and also configured php.ini but it seems that I can't connect to mongodb via my php code. Example

```
<?php
   // connect to mongodb
   $m = new MongoClient();

   echo "Connection to database successfully";
   // select a database

?>
```

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'MongoClient' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\date\include\db2.php:3 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\date\include\db2.php on line 3

Comment: Did you install mongoDB? Just like you need MySQL server installed you also need the mongo DBMS installed

Comment: Hey @RiggsFolly I installed it, I am good in mongodb but this things seems weird in my new system. That's why raised here.

Comment: Is this any use to you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24533938/class-mongoclient-not-found

Comment: The plugin is not loaded, I seen this post before @RiggsFolly and should it be php_mongo.dll or php_mongodb.dll

Comment: What version of PHP?

Comment: Did you loook at the output from `phpinfo()`

Comment: Version 7.2.1, I think this is causing the issue. As some class is depreciated, but I don't know exactly which is causing the issues.

Comment: Are you sure this is not what you are looking for https://stackoverflow.com/a/38007889/2310830

Comment: @RiggsFolly the problem is with the php version where the class mongoclient is depreciated as my update my system, I forget to check the php version is compatible, so used the composer to install the mongo library then loaded and everything works fine.

Comment: Post an answer and then this question will be useful to someone else.