# Got error 'PHP message: PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'MongoClient' not found in /var/www/html/dbtest.php:5

Tags: php, mongodb

I've installed MongoDB on my server and I'm trying to run this script:

```
<?php

$client = new MongoClient();
$collection = $client->cryptnote->storedMessages;

function insertDocument($collection, $id, $telegramuser, $message) {
    $doc = array(
        "id" => $id,
        "telegram" => $telegramuser,
        "encrypted" => $message,
    );
    try {
        $collection->insert($doc);
    } catch(Exception $e) {
        echo "Error" . $e;
    }
}

function findDocument($collection, $id){
    return $collection->findOne(["id" => $id]);
}

insertDocument($collection, "test123", "usertest", "message. test.");
$query = findDocument($collection, "test123");
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($query);
```

This is the error I get: 
`Got error 'PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'MongoClient' not found in /var/www/html/dbtest.php:5`

My Apache server uses `/etc/php/7.3/fpm/php.ini` according to `phpinfo();`.

Adding `extension=mongodb.so` to the `php.ini` file is useless.

Comment: There is a solution here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24533938/class-mongoclient-not-found/26532297

Comment: I did this and it doesn’t work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to restart `php-fpm`.

In my case I have PHP version 7.3 installed, so I needed to run this command:
`sudo service php7.3-fpm restart`